# Days Between Dates (Python)

Tags: python, date

I am trying to solve this optional problem on Udacity's CS-101 course - it asks to calculate number of days between two dates. My code works for all the test cases but for some reason it doesn't work for the case 1 (1st January 2012 - 28th February 2012), it returns 56 however the actual answer is 58. I am not able to wrap by head around that, any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
def leap_year(year):
    if year % 4 != 0:
        return "Common Year"
    elif year % 100 != 0:
        return "Leap Year"
    elif year % 400 != 0:
        return "Common Year"
    else:
        return "Leap Year"

def days_in_month(month):
    months = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    i = 0
    days = 0
    while i <= month:
        days += months[i- 1]
        i += 1
    return days


def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    i = year1
    leap_count = 0
    while i <= year2:
        if leap_year(i) == "Leap Year":
            leap_count += 1
        i += 1
    return ((year2 - year1) * 365 + (days_in_month(month2) - days_in_month(month1)) + (day2 - day1)) + leap_count

# Test routine

def test():
    test_cases = [((2012,1,1,2012,2,28), 58), 
                  ((2012,1,1,2012,3,1), 60),
                  ((2011,6,30,2012,6,30), 366),
                  ((2011,1,1,2012,8,8), 585 ),
                  ((1900,1,1,1999,12,31), 36523)]
    for (args, answer) in test_cases:
        result = daysBetweenDates(*args)
        if result != answer:
            print "Test with data:", args, "failed"
        else:
            print "Test case passed!"

test()
```

Comment: Not sure if you are allowed to use the datetime module but it could be as simple as `abs((date(2012, 1, 1) - date(2012, 2, 28)).days)`

Comment: @AndrewFarber hey thanks for that, but I would like to solve it without any inbuilt functionality, just would like to understand the actual algorithm.

Comment: I never understood that sentiment. "Here's your solution." "No, I don't want the solution, I want to reinvent the wheel!" :P

Comment: @AdamSmith lol sometimes it is good, to understand the inner working of a solution, to understand the real logic behind it, don't you think? I think that's also called engineering :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues in your `daysBetweenDates` function's body -- calendric computations are **very** difficult so I commend you for trying them, but, man!, you **are** in for a world of pain (pretty unrelated to Python -- it's all about how crazy our calendar is!-).

Consider, for example, just your final `return`ed expression:

```
((year2 - year1) * 365 + (days_in_month(month2) - days_in_month(month1)) + (day2 - day1)) + leap_count
```

Why would you add `leap_count` (previously computed as number of leap years between year1 and year2 included) **unconditionally**?!  Think about it.  Get an edge case to simplify your reasoning.  Suppose year1 and year are the same and ditto for month1 and month2.  Now leap_count will be 1 if the year is bisextile, else 0 -- and **why** could the nature of the year possibly matter **at all** to compute the days between, e.g, Jan 1 and Jan 9, or May 1 and May 9?!

Yet by your formula you're **making** it matter willy-nilly -- so you **are** going to claim that those difference are not equal in 2012 (bisextile) vs 2013 (not bisextile), which you **know** is wrong.

That's only one example of the many tricks of calendric computations you're likely falling into, alas!

I think you need a completely different algorithm.  I suspect it's simplest to distinguish whether the start and end dates are in the same year, or not.  If yes, you care about leap years only if February is between the two dates.  If no, counting days in in-between years does need checking for leap years (roughly as you're doing now).  Either way, auxiliary functions such as "days since year start" and/or "days to year end" are your friends...!-)

Comment: That was helpful Alex.  Just don't get it, why someone down-voted my post (so much hatred on stackoverflow) lol

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming later looking for how to do this the normal Python way, you should do:

```
import datetime

def delta_days(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    return abs(datetime.date(year1, month1, day1) - \
               datetime.date(year2, month2, day2)).days
```